# Mean of Standard Normal Distribution after Infinite 'flippings' over the mean of the distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution, half-normal-distribution

Let $Y_0 \sim N(0,1)$. Then $Y_1 = \left|Y_0\right|$ follows the [half-normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-normal_distribution) and $\overline{Y_1} = \sqrt{\frac {2}{\pi}}$. This is considered one iteration of a "flipping". A second iteration of a flipping would be $Y_2 = \left|Y_1 - \sqrt{\frac {2}{\pi}}\right| + \sqrt{\frac {2}{\pi}}$. Thus, the $i$th flipping can be defined as:
$$Y_i = \left|Y_{i-1} - \overline{Y_{i-1}}\right| + \overline{Y_{i-1}}\text{ ; } Y_0 \sim N(0,1)$$

> What is $\overline{Y_i}$ as $i \to \infty$? Also, can $\overline{Y_i}$ be expressed as an explicit function?

I believe that $\overline{Y_i} = O\left(\ln{i}\right)$ so $\displaystyle{\lim_{i \to \infty}} \overline{Y_i} = \infty$ based on the following logarithmic function I fitted after a simulation of $10000$ "flippings". But, I don't know how to prove this. Note that $\overline{Y_i}$ eventually grows slower than the logarithmic function in the following plot, so it may converge also.
[image]

Comment: I think your axis labels are swapped?

Comment: Fixed it, thanks for pointing out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The details of this are probably intractable, but the long-term behaviour can be analyzed. After many reflections, almost all the probability is concentrated near the expected value, and only an improbable unreflected tail remains. We can model this as a delta distribution at $y$ plus the tail at $x\gt y$. The expectation of this distribution is

$$
y+\int_y^\infty(x-y)\frac{\mathrm e^{-\frac{x^2}2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\mathrm dx=y+\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\left(\mathrm e^{-\frac{y^2}2}-y\int_y^\infty\mathrm e^{-\frac{x^2}2}\mathrm dx\right)\;.
$$

With

\begin{eqnarray*}
\int_y^\infty\mathrm e^{-\frac{x^2}2}\mathrm dx
&=&
\int_y^\infty\frac1x\cdot x\mathrm e^{-\frac{x^2}2}\mathrm dx
\\
&=&
\left[-\frac1x\mathrm e^{-\frac{x^2}2}\right]_y^\infty-\int_y^\infty\frac1{x^2}\mathrm e^{-\frac{x^2}2}\mathrm dx
\\
&=&
\frac1y\mathrm e^{-\frac{y^2}2}-\int_y^\infty\frac1{x^3}\cdot x\mathrm e^{-\frac{x^2}2}\mathrm dx
\\
&=&
\frac1y\mathrm e^{-\frac{y^2}2}+\left[\frac1{x^3}\mathrm e^{-\frac{x^2}2}\right]_y^\infty+3\int_y^\infty\frac1{x^4}\mathrm e^{-\frac{x^2}2}\mathrm dx
\\
&=&
\frac1y\mathrm e^{-\frac{y^2}2}-\frac1{y^3}\mathrm e^{-\frac{y^2}2}+O\left(\frac1{y^5}\mathrm e^{-\frac{y^2}2}\right)\;,
\end{eqnarray*}

this becomes

$$
y+\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\frac1{y^2}\mathrm e^{-\frac{y^2}2}+O\left(\frac1{y^4}\mathrm e^{-\frac{y^2}2}\right)\;.
$$

Reflecting the delta distribution in this expectation shifts it forward by approximately $\sqrt{\frac2\pi}\frac1{y^2}\mathrm e^{-\frac{y^2}2}$. If we consider $y$ as a function of the step count $t$, this yields the approximate differential equation

$$
\dot y=\sqrt{\frac2\pi}\frac1{y^2}\mathrm e^{-\frac{y^2}2}\;,
$$

and then separating variables leads to

$$
\int y^2\mathrm e^{\frac{y^2}2}\mathrm dy=\sqrt{\frac2\pi}\int\mathrm dt\;.
$$

This could be analyzed in more detail, but if we take logarithms, the dominant contributions will be $\frac{y^2}2$ on the left and $\log t$ on the right, so we get

$$
\frac{y^2}2\approx\log t
$$

and thus

$$
y\approx\sqrt{2\log t}\;,
$$

which confirms your observation of sublogarithmic behaviour.

---

Since you tried to improve on the approximation in a comment (presumably to achieve better agreement with your data), here are three improvements.

On the right, there’s an additional term $\log\sqrt{\frac2\pi}$, and $t$ is really $t-t_0$ with a free integration constant $t_0$. On the left, we have

$$
\int y^2\mathrm e^{\frac{y^2}2}\mathrm dy=y\mathrm e^{\frac{y^2}2}+O\left(\frac1y\mathrm e^{\frac{y^2}2}\right)\;.
$$

Solving the resulting equation

$$
2\log y+y^2=\log\frac2\pi+2\log(t-t_0)
$$

yields

$$
y=\sqrt{\log\frac2\pi+2\log(t-t_0)}
$$

in a first approximation, and substituting that into $\log y$ yields an improved approximation

$$
y=\sqrt{\log\frac2\pi+2\log(t-t_0)-\log\left(\log\frac2\pi+2\log(t-t_0)\right)}\;.
$$

Even without fitting $t_0$, setting $t_0=0$ again, this is closer to your data, e.g. about $3.88$ instead of $4.24$ at $t=10000$.

Comment: Yes, I also noted the improbable unreflected tail. Nice approach with recursive IBP. Would the final differential equation have a better estimation of $y \approx \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}\ln{t}}$?

Comment: @edit_profile: I don't think so. I realize that that fits your data better, but I don't see where that factor could come from. There are lots of approximations here though that you could improve on, e.g. I dropped $\log\sqrt{\frac2\pi}$, I wrote $t$ instead of $t-t_0$, the left-hand side cleary has correction terms, etc. (By the way, the approach with iterated integration by parts is from the Wikipedia article on the error function (the section on [asymptotic expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function#Asymptotic_expansion)).)

Comment: @edit_profile: I edited the answer with some improvements. You can improve further e.g. by continuing to integrate by parts on the left and iteratively substituting approximations for the non-dominating instances of $y$.

Comment: Why is the lhs of the first equation not $y+\int_y^\infty x \frac{e^{-x^2/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}dx$, based on the description you gave?

Comment: @Snoop: Because you don't get $y$ from the delta distribution, you only get $y$ times the probability of the delta distribution, which is $1$ minus the probability in the tail, so you have to subtract $y$ in the tail.

Comment: @joriki ah, of course! Thank you.

Comment: Do you think that all distributions with unbounded range would also have infinite means after infinite 'flippings'? Whereas distributions bounded to a range obviously have finite means.

Comment: @edit_profile: Yes, I think so. Because the derivative of $y$ depends only on $y$ and not on $t$, no matter how quickly it decays with $y$, you can always take it to the left-hand side and integrate to get some increasing, non-singular function of $y$ essentially equal to $\log t$, so eventually, even if extremely slowly, it will take on arbitrarily large values of $y$.